# How could I have the right type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Sorry for the Title, really don't know what name would suite this question.

I want to create a setItem function what gonna set a key in an object to a value:

```
const setItem = <T, U extends keyof T>(obj: T) => (key: U, value): void => {
    obj[key] = value
}

const person = {
    name: 'James',
    age: 13,
}

const setPerson = setItem(person)
setPerson('name', 125)
```

No compile time errors even thought we set the name property to a number. (because the value right now is typeof any).

So how could I say to TS to have obj[key] as the typeof value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on `--strict` compiler mode so that `value` gives you an "implicit `any`" warning.  The type of `value` should be `T[U]`, a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).

Note that if you want a curried generic function to work properly, you need to put your type parameters in the right place:

```
const setItem = <T>(obj: T) => <U extends keyof T>(key: U, value: T[U]): void => {
    obj[key] = value;
}
```

You want `setItem(obj)` to return a generic function that can accept any `U extends keyof T` for `key`, so the `U` parameter should be on that returned function.  If you put `<T, U>` on the first function, then the compiler will try to infer `U` from the values passed to `setIem()`, and it won't be able to.  It will end up widening `U` all the way to `keyof T`, and that will fail to prevent errors.

Let's make sure the version here works:

```
const person = {
    name: 'James',
    age: 13,
}
const setPerson = setItem(person)
setPerson('name', 10); // error
setPerson('name', 'Jill'); // okay
setPerson('age', 10); // okay
setPerson('age', 'Jill'); // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmUCSV4FsYF4YB4AqAfABQgBGAVgFwx4CUWBuAqjPAB6pgAmEMA1vACeIAGY1iAKBj8h1JgBopMAG4BDADYBXeNTwBtJgF0JtaspABLLgxgBvJWXJ6Bgw1hUbtAbgkBfHxKgkLAADvAAThDg7vbSYKpoOjAARABSCfAQyYrSqgDmSQCMAMx+PkHQcIgAChFRYO4IyKhoRGGR4LQ+TbUdYETJ8YnZMIUADF0wAPRTrOHhIOESPXXgA0PwI2kW6urJkzMwIHyqgss1q-3J+ZvyoxNe07PHp+dQvfUDN1upO3sHswiCyWQA)

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Cool stuff, thanks!
At first I received ok with the value: T[U], but after put the declaring U at the right side the compiler thrown an error!

Comment: Are you saying you still have an error?  Or is everything okay?

Comment: I mean, its a good thing I have an error with the wrong type :D. So your solution solved my problem. :)